# Why are not updating records in the migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I wrote this code in which I tried to show everything as transparently as possible:

```rb
Employee.find(7634).update!(company_id: 1)
```

This code is exactly correct and working. It works in `rails c`.

But it doesn't work in migration:

```rb
class UpdatingCompaniesForEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    Employee.find(7634).update!(company_id: 1)
  end
end
```

The SQL looks like this when executed:

> Employee Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "employees" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "employees"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2020-12-16 17:08:38.131271"], ["id", 7634]]

That is, there is no mention of the company.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class UpdatingCompaniesForEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    Employee.reset_column_information
    Employee.find(7634).update!(company_id: 1)
  end
end
```